# CSS HTML List Item Classes

Tags: html, css, list, class, html-lists

I am trying to create an ordered list of tasks.  As each task is completed, the task turns green, and the line becomes solid.  I am looking for help on the static example below.

I have seen some examples of doing this, but I am struggling with the lines and colors.  If I use ul li.circle:after for the circle, and ul li.circle:before for the line, I can get it to connect, but they all become solid lines, I cant figure out how to interchange with a dotted line.  I would like to use list items to define the line, and color of circle.

In the css there is padding: 0 0 20px 50px; which is why the lines do not connect to the dots as desired, but without the padding, there is no spacing between.  To change the color, I can change the color of all, using before/after but I cannot add another class as shown below for the color.

The start css class should be a line with a top, like a letter T, and the arrowDown should have a stem to connect to the dotted line.

The CSS File and lay out of the page:

```css
.red {
      background: #ff0000;
    }
    
    .green {
      background: #00ff00;
    }

    .start {
    /* polygon? T like shape*/
    }
    
    ul {
      max-width: 400px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    
    ul li {
      padding: 0 0 20px 50px;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    /* Circle */
    ul li.circle:after {
      position: absolute;
      color: #ccc;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      content: '';
      border: 2px solid #fff;
      border-radius: 50%;
      height: 24px;
      width: 24px;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 24px;
      background: #000000;
    }
    
    /* Circle
    ul li.circle:before {
      position: absolute;
      left: 10px;
      top: 0px;
      content: "";
      height: 100%;
      width: 0;
      border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;
    }
    */
    
    /* Line */
    ul li.line:before {
      position: absolute;
      left: 10px;
      top: 0px;
      content: "";
      height: 100%;
      width: 0;
      border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;
    }
    
    /* dottedLine */
    ul li.dottedLine:before {
      position: absolute;
      left: 10px;
      top: 0px;
      content: "";
      height: 100%;
      width: 0;
      border-left: 2px dotted #ffffff;
    }
    
    /* Missing the stem */
    ul li.arrowDown:after {
      position: absolute;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      top: 10px;
      left: 4px;
      content: '';
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 24px;
      border: solid #ffffff;
      border-width: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 6px;
    }
```

```html
<li>
<li class="start">Monday</li>
<li class="line"></li>
<li class="circle green">Task 1</li>
<li class="line"></li>
<li class="circle green">Task 2</li>
<li class="dottedLine"></li>
<li class="circle red">Task 3</li>
<li class="dottedLine"></li>
<li class="arrowDown">Tuesday</li>
</ul>
```

Please see the attached for desired output from above.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoIsC.png)

Comment: Can you show us an image of what you are trying to achieve? It will help us if we can see what it is you want to do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your opening `ul` is a `li`

Then to style as you want you would need to add a height to `.line` and `.dottedline` classes like so.

```
ul li.line, ul li.dottedLine {
  height: 20px
}
```

make you padding `padding: 0 0 10px 50px;` for ul li

For you start class use a before pseudo class

For you circle background colour add the color to the  `ul li.circle:after` and then over ride it for `ul li.red:after`

Here is the code with adjustments

```css
body {
     background: black;
}

.red {
  /* Not needed add color to pseudo element
   * background: #ff0000;*/
}

.green {
  /* Not needed add color to pseudo element
   * background: #00ff00;*/
}

.start {
/* See below: ul li.start:before */
}

ul {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
}
ul li {
  padding: 0 0 10px 50px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Circle */
ul li.circle:after {
  position: absolute;
  color: #ccc;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #00ff00;
}
ul li.red:after {
  background: #ff0000;
}

/* Line */
ul li.line {
  list-style-type:none;
}
ul li.line, ul li.dottedLine {
  height: 20px;
}

/* make the first line which is 2nd child 0 */
ul li:nth-child(2) {
  height: 10px;
}

ul li.line:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 13px;
  top: 0px;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

/* dottedLine */
ul li.dottedLine:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 13px;
  top: 0px;
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 2px dotted #ffffff;
}

/* Start T top added */
ul li.start:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 26px;
  left: 0;
  top: 24%;
  border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
  background: white;
}

/* Missing the stem 
 * stem added with pseudo class               
 * start:after slightly modified below
 */
ul li.start:after, ul li.arrowDown:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 13px;
  top: 0px;
  content: "";
  height: 90%;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;
}   
ul li.start:after {
  top: 24%;
  height: 78%;
}
ul li.arrowDown:after {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 10px;
  left: 7px;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 24px;
  border: solid #ffffff;
  border-width: 0px 3px 3px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li class="start">Monday</li>
<li class="line"></li>
<li class="circle green">Task 1</li>
<li class="line"></li>
<li class="circle green">Task 2</li>
<li class="dottedLine"></li>
<li class="circle red">Task 3</li>
<li class="dottedLine"></li>
<li class="arrowDown">Tuesday</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to Stack Overflow. However please note that questions and answers should be self-contained and not rely on external links as they can change or break over time. It is ok to include them as long as you *also* include the code in the answer itself. You can add the code to a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) using the `[<>]` button in the editor.

Comment: thanks @FluffyKitten I added the code as a Stack Snippet

Comment: Thank you.  With a little tweaking, I can get this to do what I need to.

Comment: @mike yes a few more tweaks and it will be good, lining up the text with the centre of the circle could be nice. Glad to have been of help.

Comment: maybe you could open a new question? it seems unrelated to the original. you said that the markup had to remain as is or you can not add a new class? you said" but I cannot add another class" please explain.

Comment: Thank you for following up.  Using the advice from here, I was able to accomplish what was needed.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: no problems @Mike , quite happy to help out, I see you did in fact open another question, did the answer there suffice?

Comment: Yes, I am very thankful.  I was able to change colors of the lines for sub items using   <li class="subitems blue">  and ul li.blue:after {border-color: #063dae;} but now I am trying to define colors for the lines and box at once.  For example: .blue {background-color: #063dae;border-color: #063dae;color: #ffffff;content: 'in-Progress';}  This doesnt work yet.

Comment: the content property only works with  ::before and ::after pseudo-elements if I understand correctly so your .blue{} rule won't work with content: 'in-Progress';